# How to avoid identity theft at key signing parties?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, pgp, gnupg, identity-theft

Let me begin by distinguishing two kinds of identity theft:

1. Conventional identity theft (e.g. using credentials from ID documents, bank accounts, etc, to commit fraud or [other mischief](http://www.wired.com/2012/08/apple-amazon-mat-honan-hacking/all/)).
2. Cryptographic identity theft (e.g. using a PGP certificate (aka "key") to impersonate another PGP/GPG user without their permission).

[Key signing parties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signing_party) (KSPs) are intended to make cryptographic identity theft harder, but as they [typically](http://keysigning.org/methods/sassaman-efficient) require exposing credentials from government-issued ID documents, bills, or similar, to people who would not normally have access to them, they would seem to increase the risk of conventional identity theft.

I can think of a couple of ways to mitigate against this increased risk:

- Covering [passport numbers, dates of birth](http://www.aboutidentitytheft.co.uk/passport-details-date-birth-can-be-used.html), [driving license numbers](http://manvsdebt.com/top-16-pieces-of-your-information-identity-thieves-crave/), etc, before showing the document at a KSP;
- Only signing keys belonging to people known well enough that the showing of additional credentials is not required (e.g. family, or long-standing close friends), and expecting the same in return;

However, the first might reduce trust, and the second would seem to make KSPs unnecessary.

So, I'd be grateful for others' views on how people should gain the benefits of KSPs without putting themselves at increased risk of conventional identity theft, and for pointers towards any research that has addressed this.

Comment: After I've read the comments, I conclude that this question seems to be a troll for argumentation rather than a request for information.

Comment: @BobBrown I'm sorry you've reached that conclusion, because it's mistaken. My question and comments were in earnest. I felt it was better to give constructive feedback on the answers that I found unhelpful than to simply downvote them or to say/do nothing. If you think I was wrong to do this, please explain how I could have conducted myself better.

Comment: @BobBrown You need to understand that people live in different jurisdictions, where different laws apply. For example here in sweden, if you buy someting on post-payment, or open a mobile subscription, often your SSN expressed verbally is enough. Retailers rarely ask for ID because theres no such requirement in law, making people easly victims to identity theft and people can get billed for things they didnt buy, and be obliged by law to pay the bill. Thus people need to take different precautions in different juridisctions.

Comment: @sebastiannielsen:  I do understand that.  In the United States something similar applies with credit card numbers, although there's a rather small legal limit to responsibility.  Yet, I expose my credit card number every time I buy something.  Although that credit card is not "identification," I wouldn't worry about exposing it at a key-signing party if there were reason to do so because a) one supposedly trusts everyone there, and b) without eidetic memory, no one is going to remember the number anyway.

Comment: @BobBrown, at [some](https://people.debian.org/~anibal/ksp-dc6/ksp-dc6.html) [KSPs](https://archive.fosdem.org/2014/keysigning/), at least some participants are mutual strangers, hence [the need for ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Zimmermann%E2%80%93Sassaman_key-signing_protocol&oldid=620115708). In these cases, your `a)` is false; but you *may* choose to trust that the ID documents shown by a stranger are accurate & that the stranger is genuinely in control of a given PGP key. That is very different from trusting the stranger not to engage in identity theft against you.

Comment: @BobBrown The difference is that a CC is less of a concern since it has a limit or the CC is charged with a small amount of funds. If someone gets hold of your SSN (which in sweden is only birth date + 4 extra digits, pretty easy to remember), they can order things for unlimited sums. Even if single Companys have a credit limit, the fraudster can redo the fraud at multiple companies to get a person in debt for millions of dollars. Actually, I would rather give out my CC which is only charged with about 50$ from day to day, than my SSN which is charged with "unlimited".

Comment: @sebastiannielsen, also, if it were necessary in the case of identity theft, presumably it would be much less trouble over all to get your credit card company to cancel the credit card and issue a replacement with a new number, and then to update any necessary recurring bills, etc, than it would be to cancel your SSN and get the government to issue you with a new one, and then to update all the other records that depended on the original SSN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think the questioner is living in a country like Sweden, where anyone who gets hold of your social security number, can use it to order things on post-payment in your name and have the bill sent to you instead of to delivery adress, and then you become obliged to pay the bill for someone elses Products.

The recommended solution for this is [Notary Public](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary_public). A notary public is a third-party, often government-employed person, who works at a Court or similiar instution, which verifies things in a manner you request.
If the notary is knowledgeable and knows about PGP, the notary can sign your PGP key from the very first beginning, without fear of identity theft.

But if the notary knows nothing about PGP, you can ask the notary creating a identity verifying document, containing only the neccesary details. For example, your first name, your last name, country of issuance and your current age, and then affix this document with a validity period of lets say 6 months (to make sure the age stays consistent with your real age during the document's whole validy period), and then a photo.

Of course, you show your ID to the notary. The notary is generally a trusted person, basically as trusted as a judge.
The notary signs this, often a water-marked document, and stamps this with the official notary stamp in your country.
The notary can also cross-check the verified details with the official records to even add a layer of verification.

This document is the one you bring to KSPs. A signer at KSP can then verify that the notary document is real, and in doubt, the verifier can call the notary and the notary will assure him that he did see the real ID card.
That is a solution that does not get as "suspicious" as masking off details on your ID card.

Thus you do not reveal more than necessary, and theres no risk someone uses your SSN to go haywire on the internet with post-payment order websites.

There is also possible you could do the identification process and have your PGP key signed by a [ENotary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENotary), that can assess your identity remotely over a webcam+sound Connection.

Comment: Thank you! It had not occurred to me that a notary public might be useful for reducing conventional identity theft risks at KSPs.

Comment: I've thought about your idea of a notary public signing a document with safe information to share. (First name, last name, location, photo.) This sounds good at first, but the more legal documents / etc that you create that depend upon the trust of that first notary public signed document, the more at risk your house of straw is for a simple trick. Physical documents can be altered, even those where a notary public has stamped it. (The huge weakness of the existing legal system and one large reason to use digital signatures. You're securing / signing the entire contents of the document.)

Answer (score 4):

At a key-signing party, you *show* documents, you don't hand them over, nor is there an opportunity to copy them.  Someone with an eidetic memory and an evil side might be a risk.  However, eidetic memory is rare in adults.  (So is evil, happily.)

So, specific advice in answer to your question: a key-signing party should have guests known to the host, or "second order" guests, that is guests known to a guest in attendance who is himself known to the host.  Also, the host will necessarily keep a list of the guests in order for the KSP to function.  I think the risk is small.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that the documents are typically only shown, and not handed over. I am not convinced that this means there is no opportunity to copy them (or at least, parts of them), e.g. using memorisation, handwritten notes, hidden cameras, hidden RFID passport readers, etc.

Comment: @sampablokuper If the KSP is of that much concern to you, then do not exchange keys with people you don't trust enough to be able to look at your ID for a few seconds. Also try placing yourself in a risk matrix to see if you should reasonably be worried.

Comment: @cremefraiche fair enough, but it is still odd that this does not seem to be much of a concern to *other* people, especially to people sufficiently concerned about security that they are taking active steps (i.e. participating in a KSP) to counter cryptographic identity theft, which I believe is much rarer than conventional identity theft and which might in many people's cases have less severe consequences. I don't know why this isn't more remarked upon. I feel like there's a [cognitive bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias) at play.

Comment: @sampablokuper It seems you are missing the core concept of 'web of trust'. How can you establish a web of trust if you trust no-one enough to let them verify you are who you say you are? If anonymity is your concern, perhaps PGP is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @cremefraiche, you are mistaken to say I trust no-one enough to let them verify I am who I say I am. I would be grateful for answers to my original question, rather than speculation or hyperbole.

Comment: @sampablokuper Well your question inherently implies otherwise.

Comment: @cremefraiche, I've re-read it several times and no, really, it doesn't. Hint: just because something is not required doesn't imply it is never permitted.

Answer (score 2):

### Identity Theft

If you're scared of identity theft by people reading your documents, don't go to key signing parties. Also better don't travel, as you might have to show your passport at the airport (even to normal airline staff). I'd also consider not using credit cards any more, the cashier might copy the credit card ID, and as I experienced in the US you also often have to show some identity card like your driving license. Ever rented a car? They even make copies of your documents...

### At Key Signing Parties

I don't think anybody will care about a covered passport number, as it's hard to verify during key signing anyway. People *will* care about your date of birth, as this can be used for some plausibility check. I don't remember anybody having shown bank or credit cards at key signing parties, so their information shouldn't be considered in danger.

Also, attention on cameras is very high at key signing parties. I don't think somebody would even *consider* bringing a camera, or being kindly asked to remove it within seconds.

I'd guess paying at the groceries (and other places) is considerably more doubtful considering identity theft: you're revealing more documents, and cameras are much more widespread and generally accepted.

Comment: Thanks, but a requirement to show an ID to certain people in order to travel says nothing about the risk in showing it to anyone *else*, esp. to a stranger at a KSP who might have a hidden camera. [RMS's approach to credit/debit cards](https://stallman.org/rms-lifestyle.html) probably *is* sensible from a privacy and identity theft perspective. You appear to have some experience of KSPs so I'd like to think you could offer more helpful advice, but I'm afraid your answer as it stands seems to take an all-or-nothing approach rather than a risk mitigation approach.

Comment: In the end, it boils down to what you fear. Properly verifying a document requires getting hold of it, for having a look at security features like holograms and microprinting. Don't expect getting signed by anybody taking verification serious if you don't hand over documents, and these are the ones providing at least some significance in the web of trust. Would be a nice experiment though, not handing over your documents and counting how many even refuse to look at them in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Colorado **notary public**, **electronic notary**, and a **PGP key** user.

The primary purpose of a notary is to **prevent fraud** in legal documents by **verifying the identity** of a document signer, using a satisfactory form of identification authorized by notary law. This is usually a federal or state government issued **ID card** that includes a photo and signature.

A key owner could bind their identity to a PGP public key by completing a sworn **Affidavit of Identity and Email** address before a notary public. The notary will verify the identity of the signer and place the signer under oath to tell the truth, under criminal penalty of **perjury**.

The key owner and the notary both sign the affidavit. The notary includes a notarial certificate and a **notary stamp**, acting as an authorized **government official**.  The affidavit does not include the non-public ID number of the key owner. The notary should not record the ID number in the notary journal.

A notarized key owner affidavit can be shown to other PGP key users at a group meeting, one-on-one meeting, posted on a website, or sent by email, to bind the person, email address, and PGP public key to that person.

I have created a sample form [**Affidavit of Identity and Email**](https://abclegaldocs.com/blog-Colorado-Notary/wp-content/uploads/Affidavit-of-Identity-Email.pdf) that includes the PGP key owner information, email address, and PGP key ID.

The key owner can choose a local **long-time notary** with a **long-time website** and good reputation to increase **trust**. The notary's official status can be verified using the Secretary of State's online **notary database**.

The notary does not keep a copy of the ID card or the affidavit. The notary does not need to know anything about PGP keys. The notary **does not read or verify** the content of the affidavit is true. It is the **sworn testimony** of the key owner.

A notary does not certify PGP keys or verify email addresses. That is not an authorized notarial act.

However, as an additional **non-notarial business service**, an enterprising notary familiar with PGP keys could **verify** the email address and **cryptographically certify** the key owner's public key as an **endorsement** of trust. This endorsed key is more trustworthy than a non-endorsed key, since a government notary has verified the ID of the key owner.

The PGP support business could use specialized email addresses such as **id-verify**@examplebusiness.com and **openpgp-certify**@examplebusiness.com.

There are over 4 million notaries in the U.S. who could learn about PGP keys and provide this sideline **business service** for a nominal fee. **Independent notaries** are more likely to be interested, not free notary service from a bank.

The **notary journal** would contain a record of the sworn affidavit made by the key owner, including the date, signature, and method of identification.  The **notarial certificate** on the affidavit includes the **location** (state and county) of the notarization, relating the key owner to a **geographic area**.

An authorized **electronic notary** (e-notary) can complete the affidavit using a paper document or an electronic document. With an electronic document, the **hash value** can be computed and recorded in the notary journal or on the **blockchain** to reveal evidence of data corruption or **tampering**.

A properly notarized document is considered as **valid legal evidence** on its face, prima facie evidence.